# Gulp 4 последовательно выполнить задачи

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp4

Мне нужно собрать проект с помощью gulp 4, и выполнить задачи друг за другом.

Пробую:

```
function first_task(done)
{
    setTimeout(function ()
               {
                   console.log("first task");
               }, 1000);

    done();
}

function second_task(done)
{
    console.log("second task");
    done();
}


const gulp = require("gulp");

const runner = gulp.series(first_task, second_task);

runner();
```

Вывод:

```
second task
first task
```

Как сделать так, чтобы `second_task` не запускалась пока `first_task` не отработает?

Comment: Поместить `done` в `setTimeout`.

Comment: Спасибо, оформишь как ответ, чтобы я мог решенным пометить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` - асинхронная операция. Таск `first_task` должен выполнится, когда выполнится обработчик `setTimeout`. Соответственно, `done` надо поместить внутрь `setTimeout`.

```
function first_task(done)
{
    setTimeout(function ()
               {
                   console.log("first task");
                   done();
               }, 1000);

}

function second_task(done)
{
    console.log("second task");
    done();
}


const gulp = require("gulp");

const runner = gulp.series(first_task, second_task);

runner();
```